# Reordenar array de objetos en Javascript después de eliminar un elemento

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Tengo un array de objetos en javascript:

```
  array = [
        {order:1,index2 :'whatever'},
        {order:2,index2: 'whatever'},
        {order:3,index2: 'whatever'},
        {order:4,index2: 'whatever'}
    ]
```

Si yo elimino el objecto: {order = 3,index2 = 'whatever'}, el array se quedaría así:

```
    array = [
        {order:1,index2:'whatever'},
        {order:2,index2:'whatever'},
        {order:4,index2:'whatever'}
    ]
```

¿Como podría hacer en Javascript, para que el array se quedase de esta manera? O sea, con el orden correlativo. Teniendo en cuenta de que order es un índice del objeto.

```
    array = [
        {order: 1,index2: 'whatever'},
        {order: 2,index2: 'whatever'},
        {order: 3,index2: 'whatever'}
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

esta es una opción:

Estructura correcta del array de objetos:

(Opción1)

```
 array = [
      { order: 1, index2: "whatever1" },
      { order: 2, index2: "whatever2" },
      { order: 3, index2: "whatever3" },
      { order: 4, index2: "whatever4" },
      { order: 5, index2: "whatever5" },
      { order: 6, index2: "whatever6" },
      { order: 7, index2: "whatever7" },
      { order: 8, index2: "whatever8" },
    ];
```

Averiguamos el indice del objeto que tiene como order el número 4 (aquí ponemos el deseado o una variable incluso)

```
const indiceDeElementoABorrar = array.findIndex((item) => item.order === 4);
```

Borramos el objeto que tenga el indice encontrado anteriormente

```
array.splice(indiceDeElementoABorrar, 1);
```

Recorremos todos los elementos del array, iniciando por el indice del elemento que borramos que ahora sería un número más corrido, entonces desde ese en adelante le bajamos uno a todos los order restantes.

```
for (let i = indiceDeElementoABorrar; i < array.length; i++) {
  array[i].order = array[i].order - 1;
}
```

---

Podrías volcarlo en una función que reciba como parámetro el número de order que deseas borrar y retorne el array sin ese order y con los de ahí en adelante corregidos para que todo sea correlativo.

Quedaría algo así:

(Opción2)

```
array = [
  { order: 1, index2: "whatever1" },
  { order: 2, index2: "whatever2" },
  { order: 3, index2: "whatever3" },
  { order: 4, index2: "whatever4" },
  { order: 5, index2: "whatever5" },
  { order: 6, index2: "whatever6" },
  { order: 8, index2: "whatever8" },
];


function eliminarOrder(numero) {
  const indiceDeElementoABorrar = array.findIndex(
    (item) => item.order === numero
  );
  array.splice(indiceDeElementoABorrar, 1);

  for (let i = indiceDeElementoABorrar; i < array.length; i++) {
    i > 0 ? (array[i].order = array[i - 1].order + 1) : (array[i].order = 1);
  }
  return array;
}
```

Este ejemplo incluso en vez de a partir del índice eliminado restar 1 a todos los siguientes, lo que hace en realidad es tomar el índice del anterior al eliminado, y en todas las iteraciones el order pasa a ser el order del índice anterior + 1, esto hace que si hay otro número no correlativo en cualquier otra parte del array más adelante se arregle.

---

Ejemplo con valor indiceDeElementoABorrar-1: (corresponde a opción 1)

```
order 0 valor 1
order 1 valor 1
order 2 valor 1
order 4 valor 1
```

En este ejemplo si borramos el order 1 quedaría:

```
order 0 valor 1
order 1 valor 1
order 3 valor 1
```

---

Ejemplo con valor valor indiceAnterior+1: (corresponde a opción 2)

```
order 0 valor 1
order 1 valor 1
order 2 valor 1
order 4 valor 1
```

En este ejemplo si borramos el order 1 quedaría:

```
order 0 valor 1
order 1 valor 1
order 2 valor 1
```

---

Por último este ordena todos los orders, por si había alguno salteado antes del indiceABorrar.

Quedaría así: Dejé el array desordenado a propósito.

(opción 3)

```
array = [
  { order: 1, index2: "whatever1" },
  { order: 3, index2: "whatever3" },
  { order: 4, index2: "whatever4" },
  { order: 5, index2: "whatever5" },
  { order: 6, index2: "whatever6" },
  { order: 9, index2: "whatever9" },
  { order: 11, index2: "whatever11" },
];

function eliminarOrder(numero) {
  const indiceDeElementoABorrar = array.findIndex(
    (item) => item.order === numero
  );
  array.splice(indiceDeElementoABorrar, 1);

  array.map((item, i)=> i===0 ? item.order=1 : item.order = array[i-1].order + 1)
  
  return array;
}
```

Es un poco más ineficiente porque siempre recorre absolutamente todos los orders, aunque borres el último. Pero te asegurás de que siempre queda todo bien ordenado sin importar donde estés borrando.

Supongamos que borramos el order 4 que es `{ order: 4, index2: "whatever4" }`
El resultado de esto último ejemplo sería que array quedaría así.

```
Posición: Contenido
0: {order: 1, index2: 'whatever1'}
1: {order: 2, index2: 'whatever3'}
2: {order: 3, index2: 'whatever5'}
3: {order: 4, index2: 'whatever6'}
4: {order: 5, index2: 'whatever9'}
5: {order: 6, index2: 'whatever11'}
```

Espero sirva, quedo a las ordenes.

Comment: Muchas gracias, era lo que necesitaba. Un saludo.

Comment: Me alegra que te haya servido, quedo a las ordenes. Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Según entiendo, lo que necesitas es cambiar una propiedad de cada objeto del array, y el valor a cambiar depende del índice de dicho array, se puede hacer con `map()`:

```js
const array = [
        {order:1,index2:'whatever'},
        {order:2,index2:'whatever'},
        {order:4,index2:'whatever'}
    ];

const res = array.map((e, i) => (e.order = ++i) && e);

console.log(res);
```